# Right approach for running a Twisted application in the foreground or background

Tags: python, twisted

I have a Twisted application that someone else wrote. There is a file run.py which makes it run in the foreground. There is also a twistd plugin named as service.tac that makes it run in the background. Around 90% of the code is the same in both the .py and .tac file.

Is it possible to combine the two together? Or is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the tac file in the foreground: `twistd -n -y service.tac`.

So perhaps you can just delete the `run.py` file.

Comment: Just to add a minor comment to this: `.tac` files ought to be very short; really something that imports a function from a module and then calls it with some parameters; you shouldn't have a lot of logic or even a lot of objects in the `.tac` file itself, because they're quite annoying to test properly.